# How to move "section"/change "section" margin in Pages

Tags: macos, pages, iwork

I've been a full-time Mac user for 5 or so years now, but sometimes the Apple way still confuses my Microsoft-conditioned mind.  This is especially true of iWork.  In the screenshot below, can someone tell me how to move the big, main text area up to that red line?

I've tried every setting I can find - I wouldn't be asking if I hadn't - and came up completely empty.  FYI this is one of Apple's stock resume templates.

Thanks.

[image: Pages]

Answer (score 4):

I found it!

This "section" is no section, but rather the document-proper!  The other elements are in fixed positions and that margin is set on the document.

Not entirely unexpected, I suppose.