# How to adjust the left margin in Pages' Business Resume template

Tags: pages, iwork, template

In the screenshot below, can someone tell me please how to shift the main text area to the left?

[image: How do you reduce the left margin in Pages' Business Resume template?]

From the ruler, one can see the text begins at about 6.7 cm.

Changing Document Margins from the default 2.12 cm to 0 cm helps, but still a long way from 2 cm.

No adjustment of text columns, tabs and indents proved fruitful.

Similar in nature to [How to move "section"/change "section" margin in Pages](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/143545/how-to-move-section-change-section-margin-in-pages) but this one is tougher — not even an Apple Support rep knew how to get around it other than to use "Convert to Page Layout" which removes body text altogether.

Thanks to anyone's efforts to solve the mystery.

Comment: Does moving the blue thing at the top not work?

Comment: @JMY1000 No, it refuses to move any further left than that.

Comment: @grgarside How'd you figure that out?

Comment: @JMY1000 Opened the template myself and tried.

Comment: @grgarside Ah. Silly me.

Answer (score 2):

As posted in the original question, I was not able to move the left margin for body. What I did was selected other resume type (modern resume) that had the body already in the left. Also there you can further reduce the margin all the way to the edge. Then I copied the bits that i needed from business resume over it. Kind of a hack but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just open a new file using "blank" and copy the whole column over. IT's bloody wasting my time trying to figure out how to change the column width.

Answer (score -3):

Click on "Document" menu item at top right, then "Document" in the right tab view, then you can control the placement under "Document margins" at the bottom.

Comment: *"Changing Document Margins from the default 2.12 cm to 0 cm helps, but still a long way from 2 cm."*

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but that is one of the first things I tried.