# Pages exact same font, looks sharper when using template

Tags: pages, font, iwork

I have been using the default fonts in the 'Business Resume' template and I wanted to use them in my handcrafted version [due to this bug](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/240136/how-to-adjust-the-left-margin-in-pages-business-resume-template). The fonts are pretty simple and nothing extraordinary, for example,  Helvetica Neue, Light, 10pt, black.

What I have noticed is that the fonts in the template are much cleaner, they are slightly "thinner" and just look sharper. I have pasted the text across using the *Paste and Match Style* and I have also just pasted the text and manually adjusted the fonts. Every setting I can find for the font matches but the fonts clearly do not. Is there some hidden setting for the fonts? There is no difference in the font's *Advanced Styles* nor in the *Character Styles*.

Here are a couple of images both zoomed in at 400% (leftmost being the template font):

[image: Template font (thinner and sharper)] 
[image: Standard font]

Hopefully you can see the clear difference.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: unfortunately, no. But kudos for the edit! Better now. just to clarify, are you asking for the reason of the difference, a possible bug report, or how to use the sharper version of the font?

Comment: @ankiiiiiii asking how to fix it really but if this is not possible then perhaps it would end up a bug report...